# Calculate start and end time time of the pages visited in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am stuck on a problem where I need to capture the avg time spend by the user on a module.

So, a module consists of a group of pages - say, module **Marvel** consists of pages Iron Man, Captain America, Thor. Module **DC** consists of pages Batman, Superman, Wonder Woman.

Now, there are some other pages that do not come under any modules as such, like **Contact Us** page.

Let's say for module **Marvel**, the start page is Iron Man and End Page is Thor, and in between there are multiple pages.

What I want to do is I want to capture the time when the user starts a particular module, and ends it as well using Next.js.

I did some research where I used the below code in _app.tsx, but this code will trigger the function on each page including the **Contact Us** page.

```
useEffect(() => {
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handlePageChange);

        return () => {
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handlePageChange);
        };
    }, []);
```

I just want to trigger it on the start and end page of a module and I want to keep the code clean where I don't have to trigger the function on separate pages. That is the reason I thought of using _app.tsx. I also want to exclude pages like **Contact Us** to be tracked.

Please share your valuable insights on how can I achieve that. Many thanks